# How to make Xamarin iOS UI test work with localized build?

Tags: xamarin

I wrote a UI test automation for my iOS app using visual studio, integrated with xamarin. Looking at code, the framework is finding an element by title or accessibility label (see below code snip). Unlike android UI test automation which looks for element by id, it works in English locale. But with other localization, this won't pass.

`app.Tap(x => x.Marked("Settings"));`

Do you know if there is a way to detect the locale that the app runs and use proper strings in code, or are there some other stuff I've missed here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found out the solution. Don't use Marked method, use x => x.Id(...). On iOS, this will be element's accessibility identifier. So what I need to do is to set those identifiers same as android.

Comment: Actually, Marked method will use input string to search multiple places, id is one of those.